# PostgreSQL LDAP authentication with SSL self-signed certificate

Tags: postgresql, ssl, ldap

I'm trying to setup LDAP authentication for an user on a PostgreSQL 12 instance running on RHEL 7.5.

What I've done:

- put into `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors` all the needed
  certificates starting from the one of the LDAP server to the
  internal root certification authority (which is the self-signed one) - probably only the root certificate is needed (UPDATE: only the root ca certificate is enought)
- ran `update-ca-certs extract` command to commit the changes to system
- verified the correctness of the trust chain with `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect myldapshost:636` (ldaps) that returned at the end `Verify return code: 0 (ok)`
- configured the `pg_hba.conf` entry for the user I want to authenticate against LDAP:

  `host    all        myuser         samenet                 ldap            ldapscheme=ldaps ldaptls=0 ldapserver=myldapshost ldapport=636 ldapbasedn="mybasedn" ldapbinddn="<mybinddn>" ldapbindpasswd=secret`

  - Told the server to reload configuration with `pg_ctl reload`

When I try to authenticate as `myuser` with `psql -h mypostgreshost mydb` I get this error:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  LDAP authentication failed for user "myuser"
FATAL:  LDAP authentication failed for user "myuser"
```

Looking at the PostgreSQL log I see:

```
LDAP diagnostics: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
```

The question is: how can I tell PostgreSQL to trust the self-signed certificate it find? 
Thanks

Comment: Are you able to get a working connection using `ldapsearch` (i.e., are you certain that things are working outside of Postgres)?  Not suggesting that it's busted, but it's the typical starting point for troubleshooting stuff like this--can you add the output to the post?

Comment: An ldapsearch query works perfectly, I think it's related to the way Postgres handle trusted certificates

Comment: should you have `ldaptls=1`?

Comment: Tried, same error

Comment: I've exactly the same message from GitLab before to put the certificate of my root ca in /etc/gitlab/trusted-certs directory (as described here: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/ssl.html#install-custom-public-certificates). Done this, all works! 
So, the question could be: what is the trusted ca directory/file of PGSQL12?

Comment: I think you put it in your `$PGDATA` dir -- if you look in `postgresql.conf`, you can specify `ssl_ca_file`

Comment: @richyen I tried as you suggested but the error remains. Is it possible that this parameter is used only to verify the clients?